# Do not delete if there is a FK dependency to obj

Tags: python, mysql, django

I want to do a `DELETE` operation for an item in django, but only if there are no FK dependencies. I would normally do this:

```
Catalog.objects.filter(pk=pk).delete()
```

Which would delete the item and then delete/nullify any dependencies to this particular Catalog object. However, I do not want to delete the item if there are any dependencies. How would I do that in django? I was thinking -

```
list(Catalog objects.raw('DELETE FROM main_catalog WHERE pk=%s', pk))
```

Comment: Using a raw query isn't going to do any checks for fk's unless your database is set up with cascading deletes. Do you know the foreign key fields on your model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the exists() command in your query.

```
if main_catalog.objects.filter(catalog__id=pk).exists():
    pass
else:
    Catalog.objects.filter(pk=pk).delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use a get() with a foreign key, as you only expect one object to be returned. Then check for foreign keys on that object.

```
catalog = Catalog.objects.get(pk=pk)
if  catalog.foreign_key_1 or catalog.foreign_key_2 :  # repeat or's with all fk's on the object
    pass
else : 
    catalog.delete()
```